# SVG graphic doesn't scale in IE10 and 11

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with SVG graphics on my site on IE10 and 11.

It works fine in Google-chrome and Firefox but not in Internet explorer. The graphics is tiny and I can not scale it on IE.

The SVG object is written as:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 570 910" style="enable-background:new 0 0 570 910;" xml:space="preserve" class="style-svg rule-svg6 alignnone size-full wp-image-9121 replaced-svg">
```

This is how its added in CMS Wordpress

```
<img src="http://example.net/mps/noaccess/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Prevalence-A.svg" alt="Prevalence-A" class="style-svg rule-svg2 alignnone size-full wp-image-9041" />
```

Then there is one plugin installed which render SVG:
_https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/

Each line of this graphic consists of its own rect.
So, my graphic looks:

```
<g>
            <rect x="220.2" y="196.2" class="rop110" width="736" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="106.2" class="rop110" width="699" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="256.2" class="rop110" width="829" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="76.2" class="rop110" width="642" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="226.2" class="rop110" width="456" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="46.2" class="rop110" width="365" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="166.2" class="rop110" width="596" height="28"></rect>
            <rect x="220.2" y="136.2" class="rop110" width="141" height="28"></rect>
        </g>
```

This is what I have on in Google-chrome and Firefox and it's ok.

[image]

And this is what I have on Internet Explorer: (it's tiny)

[image]

And I have a svg.image.css with this code:

```
svg.style-svg {display: inline-block;

position: relative;

width: 100%;

padding-bottom: 100%; 

vertical-align: middle; 

overflow: hidden; }
```

When I'm changing width, it works for Google-chrome and Firefox but not for Internet explorer. It stays still tiny..

I've tried to use `width: auto;` or `width: 100px;`
But it doesn't work..

Comment: @charl-steynberg Thanks bro for your answer! Very useful. But I didn't tell comprehensive information. See pls additional information I've added on my post

Answer (score 0):

You can make it scalable according to its proportions by defining the SVG object like this:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 570 910"
    style="display:block">

    <rect x="49.6" y="41.6" class="rop20" width="1119.4" height="302"></rect>

</svg>
```

Beware of your SVG contents though, see the `width=1119.4` part, it is a lot larger than the SVG "viewBox" size.

Try using an SVG graphics editor, like "Inkscape" -it's free and runs on Linux, Windows & MacOSX, which you can find here: https://inkscape.org/en/download/

After creating your SVG and saved it as "plain SVG", then you can open & edit the SVG code in your favorite text editor, making it scale according to the width & height of its container element as shown above.

If you want to use it inline -embedded with your HTML, just remove the "XML" declarations that your SVG graphics authoring software created (like Inkscape) for compatibility.